# multiple INSERTs in single CTE pipeline

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, sql-insert, common-table-expression

I have an input table that looks like this:

```
intput(code, persons)
'ID1', 'Pete Sampras,Ricky Martin,Albert Einstein'
'ID2', 'Georges Mikael, Diego Maradona'
```

I want to produce 3 output tables:

```
ids_table(idcode, code)
1, 'ID1'
2, 'ID2'

persons(idperson, FirstName, LastName)
1, 'Pete', 'Sampras'
2, 'Ricky', 'Martin'
3, 'Albert', 'Einstein'
4, 'Georges', 'Mikael'
5, 'Diego', 'Maradona'

code_persons(idcode, idperson)
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
2, 4
2, 5
```

I am using a pipeline of CTEs to do this. I was wondering if you could do multiple inserts in the same CTE pipeline. Something like:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT code, [value] AS person
    FROM input
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(persons, ',')
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT code, person, CHARINDEX(' ',person) AS splitIndex
    FROM cte
), cte3 AS (
    SELECT code, person, LEFT(person, splitIndex) AS FirstName,
        SUBSTRING(person, splitIndex, 100) AS LastName
    FROM cte2
), cte4 AS (
    INSERT INTO ids_table(code)
    SELECT DISTINCT code 
    FROM cte3
), cte5 AS (
    INSERT INTO persons(FirstName, LastName)
    SELECT FirstName, LastName
    FROM cte3
), cte6 AS (
    INSERT INTO code_persons(idcode, idpersons)
    SELECT it.idcode, p.idperson
    FROM cte3
    JOIN persons p ON p.FirstName = cte3.FirstName AND p.LastName=cte3.LastName
    JOIN ids_table it ON cte3.code=it.code
)
--Some code to trigger execution
```

One solution I can think of is to store the output of cte3 into a temporary table.

Is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: You have no `FROM` clause in cte3.

Comment: In SQL Server CTEs only allow `SELECT`. Not `INSERT`

Comment: Any reason why doing this with CTEs wouldn't be a good idea ? Or is it simply a current limitation of SQL Server ?

Comment: In SQL Server the reason why it wouldn't be a good idea is because it doesn't work there.

Comment: As per the [CTE_query_definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql#cte_query_definition), _Specifies a SELECT statement whose result set populates the common table expression. The SELECT statement for CTE_query_definition must meet the same requirements as for creating a view, except a CTE can't define another CTE._

Comment: It's a limitation, by design. Use a temp table instead.